# IE8 Jquery .mouseenter not firing

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
        $.get('http://xxxx/currencyselect.php',0, function(a) {
    $("#mat_currencydropdown").html(a) });
     $("#currencydropdown").mouseenter(function(e) {
    $("#currencydropdown").css('overflow','visible')
    $("#currencydropdown").css('border','1px #FFF solid')
    });
    $("#currencydropdown").mouseleave(function(e) {
    $("#currencydropdown").css('overflow','hidden')
    $("#currencydropdown").css('border','1px #ccc solid')
    });
});
```

Works fine in every other browser, all except IE.  It pulls the .php file in fine, just the mouseenter doesn't seem to change anything!

(before anyone asks, i cant just < ? php import('blahblah.php') ?> as the guy in charge of the DB/CMS/WMS will only allow .htm

//Answered

After trying for a while, comparing it to another page step by step on code, turns out that it was firing, but hiding under the div, it was so precise in the overflow of the surrounding div that it appeared to not have any drop down.

I guess i was right that IE was once again being a pain, just this time it was the way it handles CSS rather than JS!

Comment: If the `#currencydropdown` element is added to the DOM as a result of the AJAX `$.get()` then you should be binding the events in the success part of the AJAX call. The AJAX is asynchronous therefore the elements _might_ not be part of the DOM when the current event binding is taking place.

Comment: Yeah i noticed that too, changed it. Found the answer, will post!